# define pointer to pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to use pointer to pointer to store a dynamic array data set but I don't know how to link them together. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
How can I initialize the pointer to pointer array using dynamic array ?  And how can I pick specific data set to do further program using pointer to pointer?

```
      float *data;
      float **dataIndex;
      *dataIndex = (float**)malloc(number * sizeof(float*));

      data = (float*) malloc(size * sizeof(float));
      for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
            scanf("%f", (data + i));
      }
```

Comment: No need to cast return value from `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.

Comment: In case you are unaware, one option is `float (*dataIndex)[size] = malloc(number * sizeof(*dataIndex));`

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically allocate a 2D array, you will need to use a loop to initialize each pointer in the array.

```
float **arr;
size_t i, n;

if ((arr = malloc(n * sizeof(float *)) == NULL)
    perror("malloc");

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    if ((arr[i] = malloc(sizeof (float))) == NULL)
        perror("malloc");
```

Don't forget to free your memory.

```
while (--n >= 0)
    free(arr[n]);
free(arr);
```

You need to be careful to free each subarray first, and then free the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how allocate for pointer to pointers.

```
dataIndex = malloc(number * sizeof(float*));
for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
  dataIndex[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(float));
```

Now if you want to populate data, you need to access it like a 2D array `dataIndex[i][j]`.

```
for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
        scanf("%f", &dataIndex[i][j]);
```

Also remember to check errors and free memory.